# Type map.... does not provide a call operator

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading

Attempting to implement some overloaded operators on a class Month:

```
class Month
{
      int monthNumber;
      string name;
}
```

I was able to implement the below constructor without problems:

```
Month::Month(int cust_month) 
{
    monthNumber = cust_month;
    name = int_month.at(cust_month);
}
```

Note the use of a map (not shown) int_month where int 1-12 are mapped to corresponding month names, this works fine. But attempting to do something similar when overloading the ++ operator:

```cpp
Month Month::operator++() {
    if (monthNumber == 12) {
        monthNumber = 1;
        name = "January";
    }
    else{
        ++monthNumber;
        name = int_month(monthNumber); // ERROR

    }
    return *this;
}
```

In the above snippet int_month is highlighted and displays the error:

```
Type 'map<int, std::__1::string>' (aka 'map<int, basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >') does not provide a call operator
```

I've read similar posts and they have all resolved some sort of programming error, but after reading them I am still not sure what this error means for my code. I am curious not only how to solve it, but why using a map to assign value by key in my constructor worked fine but the same process does not work to overload an operator.

Comment: Don't you mean `.at()`, instead of `()`?

Comment: Well, if you compare how you assign it in a constructor, vs. the `++` overload, you can see a few difference. You really have to pay attention in C++ to all details. Every last possible detail matters. P.S. Your `++` operator should return a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read the error it tells you exactly about the problem:

```
Type 'map<int, std::__1::string>' (aka 'map<int, basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > >') does not provide a call operator
```

You have a map from int to string, which does not provide a call operator. That means that there is no function `std::map<...>::operator()(...)`. So what you have to do is that you should go to a reference like [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and you will see that there is no `operator()`.

Further, you will see that there is a section *Element Access*, which gives you two functions:

- `at`: access specified element with bounds checking
- `operator[]`: access or insert specified element

This tells you quite precisely which functions exist. If you check those in more details, you will also see the [function signature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), like for `operator[]`:

```
T& operator[]( const Key& key );
T& operator[]( Key&& key );
```

This means that you can either pass an rvalue or a const reference to an lvalue to the bracket operator. Also read carefully through the documentation and the code samples in the end to realize that values are inserted into the `map` if they did not exist yet (in contrary to `at` which will throw if the element does not exist).

So finally, some usage example:

```
std::map<int, std::string> m;
m[3] = "a"; // inserts "a" at position 3
std::cout << m[3]; // prints "a"
m[3] = "b"; // modifies the conetent at 3 to "b"
std::cout << m[3]; // prints "b"

m.at(3) = "c"; // modifies the content at 3 to "c"
std::cout << m[3]; // prints "b"

m.at(4) = "d"; // this will throw std::out_of_range
```